# Possible membership rollover bug

Tags: civimember

Ran into what might be a bug in the calculation of membership rollovers. Anyone else? Here are our details:

- fixed length memberships that expire on 1 December
- rollover date of 30 June (i.e. if you become a new member after 30 June, you expire at December 1st +1 year
- members renewing and new members joining before 1 December get expiration of 2021
- new members joining in December get expiration of 2022
- new members joining in January get expiration of 2021
  It looks like the system might be calculating the rollover based on 1 January and ignoring the fixed membership date of 1 December?

cheers ... :) gn